# Add image width and height in string

Tags: php, html-parsing

I have a string like this:

```
<p>This is a paragraph with an image <img src='/url-to-img.jpg' style='height:100px;width:30px;float:right;'></p>
<p>This is another paragraph with an image <img src='/url-to-img.jpg' style='margin:10px;height:100px;width:30px;float:left;'></p>
```

This string is from the database and the editor adds the image like that, unfortunately.

Now I want to edit this automatically using PHP to this:

```
<p>This is a paragraph with an image <img src='/url-to-img.jpg' style='height:100px;width:30px;float:right;' height=100 width=30 align='right'></p>
<p>This is another paragraph with an image <img src='/url-to-img.jpg' style='margin:10px;height:100px;width:30px;float:left;' height=100 width=30 align='left'></p>
```

I would like to get the height and width from the style and add them to the img tag.

Is this possible?

(This is so my image will show the alt text and not like a small square in Outlook. I want it to show as the full image)

Comment: Um, why? To what purpose?

Comment: its already defined on the style there should be no need to add the attributes.

Comment: It's for a newsletter. When I use style it doesn't show the newsletter as it should but when I use height and width it does.

Comment: @prix Tell that to Outlook. When defined in the style my image is a small square and the alt text doesn't show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [preg_match_all](http://www.php.net/manual/tr/function.preg-match-all.php) to get the width and height from style and then add these attributes using php [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/tr/function.str-replace.php). regular expression to match the width height would look like this: `height:(.*?);width:(.*?);`

```
$text = "<p>This is a paragraph with an image <img src='/url-to-img.jpg' style='height:100px;width:30px;float:right;'></p>
<p>This is another paragraph with an image <img src='/url-to-img.jpg' style='margin:10px;height:100px;width:30px;float:left;'></p>";

preg_match_all("/<img.*>/",$text,$out);
foreach($out as $t1)
{
    foreach($t1 as $img)
    {
        preg_match("/.*height:(.*?);width:(.*?);.*/",$img,$out2);
        $height = $out2[1];
        $width = $out2[2];
        $text = str_replace($out2[0],str_replace("<img","<img width='" . $width . "' height='" . $height . "'",$out2[0]),$text);
    }
}
echo $text;
```

Comment: thank you! I'm able to get all the height and widths from the string but how do I apply the preg_replace function to this? I cannot actually replace the current height or width with the new one because they are still in the style.